# Custom route in Web Api 2 to call with angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

So I have Web Api 2 set up and and doing my restful calls from Angular 5. I have a custom route that I would like to call but keep receiving a 400 error. Can someone shed a bit of light. Thanks.

**Web API Side:**

```
[Route("api/ViewAllRecords/GetApprovalRecords/{ upn }")]
public IQueryable GetViewAllRecordsForMgrApproval([FromBody]string upn)
{
    var set = db.ViewAllRecords.Where(record => record.ApproverUPN == 
     upn).AsQueryable();
    return db.ViewAllRecords;
}
```

**Angular Side:**

```
  GetRecordForApproval(upn) {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/ViewAllRecords/GetApprovalRecords', { params: {
      upn : upn
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action in question has a few issues with its definition.

`[FromBody]` wont work with HTTP GET requests as they do not have a BODY

```
//GET api/ViewAllRecords/GetApprovalRecords/upn_value_here
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ViewAllRecords/GetApprovalRecords/{upn}")]
public IQueryable GetViewAllRecordsForMgrApproval(string upn) {
    var set = db.ViewAllRecords.Where(record => record.ApproverUPN == upn).AsQueryable();
    return db.ViewAllRecords;
}
```

and secondly you have the `upn` in the route template which defines the URL but the client side is not calling a URL that would match the template.

Update the URL called from the client

```
GetRecordForApproval(upn) {
    var url = environment.apiUrl + '/ViewAllRecords/GetApprovalRecords/' + upn;
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```